# Solving a partial differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

So I'm working on a PDE problem:
$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial t^2}$$
with boundary conditions
$$u(0,t) = 0\quad \text{for}\; t>0$$
$$u_x(L,t) = 0\quad \text{for}\; t>0$$
and initial conditions
$$u(x,0) = 0$$
$$u_t(x,0) = \frac12\sin\biggl (\frac{3\pi x}{2L}\biggl)$$

Where I struggle specifically is that upon separating the variables, finding both integrals, obtaining the general solution, I still see no way to apply the initial conditions. So after applying the first initial condition I reach:

$$\frac12\sin\biggl(\frac{3\pi x}{2L}\biggl )=\sum \frac{b_n cn\pi}{L}\sin\biggl(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\biggl )$$

Which leaves me wondering how can this ever be satisfied when n is limited to integers, it appears to me that n must be 3/2, but this cannot be the case for this series.

Comment: Check your work. You should not have an $n$ appearing in front of the $\sin$ in the series.

Comment: @K.defaoite it arises from differentiating the cos(cnPit/L) term, I'm not sure how I can differentiate it without the n term appearing?

Comment: That doesn't seem right. It would help if you showed how you got here.

Comment: You were wrong when solving the Sturm-Liouville problem. You should get $X''+\lambda X=0$, $X(0)=X'(L)=0$. This problem has the solution $X(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi(n-0.5) x}{L})$. $X(x) = \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{L})$ is solution for $X''+\lambda X=0$, $X(0)=X(L)=0$